# Taking a dictionary in python and writing it to an HDF5 file

Tags: python, dictionary, hdf5

**BACKGROUND:**

I am working with large geometries that will be meshed or broken down into smaller parts and then regrouped. So, for instance, if a block was broken into 16 pieces, it might be reorganized into 4 "Patches" with 4 pieces or elements each. After this process, I still need to keep track of the elements. I assigned the patchIndex (I have a list of the number of patches) as the "key" that will give back the all the elements in the patch and their  1) local index (the index of the element within the patch) and their 2)  global index (the index of the element within the entire geometry).

**PROBLEM:**

How on earth can I get this information into an HDF5 file?

**MY CODE:**

Here is how I am setting up my dictionary if that is helpful to know:

```
def readAscii(ElementsList,gpmetisfile): 
    f = open(gpmetisfile, 'r')
    indexer={}
    i=0     
    for line in gpmetisfile:
        patchIndex = eval(line)  

        if patchIndex in indexer:
            localIndex=indexer[patchIndex]

        else:
            indexer[patchIndex]=0

        test = ElementsList[i].setLocalIndex(patchIndex,localIndex) 
        if test:
            indexer[patchIndex] +=1
```

*EDIT* - the gpmetisfile is what I use to break down the geometry into pieces. It comes in the format of the nth line corresponding to the nth element that simply has a single value, the patch it belongs to. ElementsList is a list of the elements in the geometry.

Comment: How about using h5py, http://code.google.com/p/h5py/

Comment: Thanks! I am using h5py, i'm mainly confused on the actual code I should use though.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I get a key error if I try to write a dictionary. It seems HDF5 only takes rectangular arrays of data... or at least I can't figure out how to store other things.

Comment: Yup, so far as I have found, numpy arrays are the easiest way. The dictionary feel can then be achieved by creating a hierarchy with various 'valuegroupname = keygroupname.create_group' commands. If you find another way to store other items, keep me posted!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not fully understand the details of your problem but the easiest way to work with hdf5 file is using the nice h5py library. [Here](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/) you can find the documentation.

Comment: I guess, basically, how would you put a dictionary in Python into an HDF5 file? Sorry that I elaborated so much. Thanks for the link, too!